# Member variable not properly updating before being evaluated

Tags: c++, tcp, mfc

I have a simple TCP client built in mfc. In my connection code, I iterate through different port numbers for my `Create()` call to avoid `TIME_WAIT` issues with reconnecting to the server.

Here's the code for my TCP connection dialog, with `CAsyncSocket` derived `tcpControl` class.

```
 void CTCPSettingsDlg::Connect()
{
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame *)AfxGetMainWnd();
    CLOPCDoc* pDoc = ((CLOPCDoc *)pMainFrame->GetActiveDocument());
    int nPort = 5000;

    while(nPort<6000)
    {   
        pMainFrame->CloseTCP(); // close TCP port
        OpenPort(nPort); // open TCP port to nPort
        pDoc->tcpControl.Connect(m_szHostIP,atoi(m_szPort));
        nPort++;
        if(m_bState == CONNECTED) break;
    }
}
```

MFC's tcpControl::OnConnect is called if the connection is succesful, which is overriden to set the dialog's `m_bState` member variable to CONNECTED.

However, even if the connection is succesful, the `break` is never executed because the code block does not recognize the change to `m_bState`.

Putting an `AfxMessageBox()` call just before the `if` statement results in the code executing properly.

All this code is running in a single thread. I'm confused as to why the member variable isn't being updated on time for it to be caught by the `if` statement.

I'm new to network programming; please feel free to let me know if it looks like I'm doing anything silly with respect to the way I have my socket set up.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're inheriting from `CAsyncSocket`, which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m_bState does not change because you are executing a while loop. The OnConnect is not called until you pump messages. (It is a message handler.) Returning to MFC will pump messages, or displaying a MessageBox will pump messages.

Get rid of the while loop and do the next step when OnConnect is called.